# Unable to edit text value in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

When hovered over the text 'Bedroom', the blue dotted box appears over it, but clicking on it, does not place the cursor, as if it is read-only.

However, I am able to edit the rendered images. And also the text 'Water View Loft' coming from another repeater, without issues.

[image]

**ascx:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpPhotos" runat="server" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="item">
     <p>
      <sc:Text runat="server" Field="Title" Item="<%#Container.DataItem %>"/>
     </p>
     <sc:Image runat="server" Field="Image" Item="<%#Container.DataItem %>" />
   </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The fields `Title` & `Image` are from a template called `Base Content`. I have used this template to render other repeater in the same user control & there I can edit the text & images.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Is your user 'admin' user? Do you have `write` access right to this field?

Comment: Yes I do. Did not make any changes in Security.

Comment: Any errors in the browsers console when you click on 'Bedroom'?

Comment: No errors in the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `<p>` tag, and see if the field gets editable. The Page Editor gets broken on nested `<p>` tags, and perhaps it happens also in your case.

Comment: No Luck. I tried without `<p>`, with & without `<div`>. But editor gets broken in such cases, how do we go about if the html design needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `DisableWebEditing="false"`.